# p-subgroup in normalizer of p-Sylow group confusion

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions, sylow-theory

I’m trying to show that if $H, S$ are subgroups with order $p^k, p^n$ inside of $G$ with order $p^n m $ (and $p,m$ relative prime), if $H$ is inside the normalizer of $S$ then $H \leq S$.

I’ve tried to proof this using group actions, but have seemed to show that distinct $p$-Sylow groups are actually the same. I can’t see where I’ve gone wrong though.

Where is my mistake, and how do I fix it and solve the problem?

My method:

Let $H$ act on the left cosets $G/S$ as follows:
$$
h \cdot gS = gh^{-1}S.
$$

Then since $H$ is a p-group, a fixed point theorem says that the number of elements stabilized by the action is equal the number of elements of the set mod $p$:
$$
|G/S|^H \equiv |G/S| \pmod p
$$

Since $S$ is a $p$-Sylow group, $p$ and $|G/S|$ are relatively prime so $|G/S|^H$ cannot be non-empty. Hence let $gS$ be fixed by all of $H$.

Then $gh^{-1}S = gS$, for all $h$, hence $gHS = gS$, so $HS = S$ and in particular $H \leq S$.

But if $H$ is some other $p$-Sylow group (and hence also a $p$-group), I don’t have $H\leq S$, hence my confusion.

Comment: Your first paragraph mentions $P$, but doesn't say who $P$ is. Is $P$ supposed to be $H$, so that your action is well-defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the $P$ in the first paragraph is supposed to be $H$. The reasons I'm going to guess that are (i) There is no $P$ mentioned until that statement; and (ii) for your action to be well-defined, you need $H$ to normalize $S$. Indeed, if $gS = xS$, then $x^{-1}g\in S$. But then to get $gh^{-1}S = xh^{-1}S$, you need $hx^{-1}gh^{-1}\in S$, but all you know is that it lies in $hSh^{-1}$. So if $H$ normalizes $S$, then this works.

If you have that assumption, then your qualm is actually born from you forgetting about this hypothesis! Note that $S\triangleleft N_G(S)$, since the normalizer is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $S$ is normal. But that means that $S$ is a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(S)$, and therefore that $S$ is the **unique** $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(S)$. Hence, you cannot have $H$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ that is both *different* from $S$ **and** contained in $N_G(S)$.

I will note that your argument for $H\leq S$ can be simplified. Once you have $gS=gh^{-1}S$, this implies $hg^{-1}g = h\in S$. Hence $H\subseteq S$.

Comment: Aiya, how could I overlook the hypothesis! Thanks for pointing this out (and the typo)! I feel so dumb. As you’ve said, the proof (and hence the statement) implies that distinct $p$-Sylow groups are contained in different normalizers.

Comment: @CookieMonster: Note also that your action is not the usual action on left cosets (which is $h\cdot (gS) = hgS$). So you should have at least checked that the action is well defined (which requires the assumption that $H$ normalizes $S$).

Comment: I thought I did! (and maybe this is a more serious error): if $gS = xS$, then $gx^{-1} \in S$. Since $gh^{-1}(xh^{-1})^{-1} = gh^{-1}hx^{-1}=gx^{-1}$, the action is well-defined.

Comment: @CookieMonster : That's wrong! $gS=xS$ if and only if $x^{-1}g\in S$, if and only if $g^{-1}x\in S$. Your check is for **right** cosets, not for left ones!

Comment: @CookieMonster: For example, in $S_3$, consider $S=\{e, (1,2)\}$. Then $(1,3)S = \{(1,3),(1,2,3)\} = (1,2,3)S$. But you would have us look at $(1,3)(1,2,3)^{-1} = (1,3)(1,3,2) = (2,3)\notin S$.

Comment: @CookieMonster: For a subgroup $H$, $xH=yH$ if and only if $y^{-1}xH = H$ if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$. For right cosets, $Hx = Hy$ if and only if $Hxy^{-1}=H$ if and only if $xy^{-1}\in H$. The action you defined would be the standard one for a left action on **right** cosets, $h\cdot (Sx) = Sxh^{-1}$.